# Android R.drawable icon to reduce zoom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons

In the Android list of `R.drawables` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html) I can find the   `ic_menu_zoom` button, which have a little plus sign inside.

[image: ic_menu_zoom]

Does anyone know about a similar menu button, but with a minus sign? I can't seem to find anything in the reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the wrong kind of icon. It clearly says that it is a menu icon `ic_menu_zoom`.

What you are really looking for is the `btn_plus_` and `btn_minus_` icons. Note that I've omitted the states. You'd actually want all button states to combine them into a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).

Alternatively you can take a look at the `btn_zoom_` icons.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm not looking for the wrong icon, just looking for one similar to ic_menu_zoom, but with a minus sign. The reason is that I have more icons in the ic_menu_(...) graphical style and I would like to keep it that way. However, seems that such an icon does not exist, wonder why!

Comment: Well because you are not really meant to trigger zoom operations from the menu directly I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try `btn_minus_default` and `btn_plus_default`.

**Edit:**

Or check out [this](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) link.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the list is pretty useful

Comment: No problem - be sure to mark as answered if this answered your question.